# Android move to sdcard fetaure

Tags: android

i have found that the move to sdcard feature is available in from 2.2 only, my problem is my os version is 2.1 ,but when it installing in 2.2 i need to enable the feature ,how can i do this, i have found that the 'Installation location attribute is available in 2.2'.

Comment: i have create the project in 2.2 and set minsdkversion 7 ,and it's working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Update your SDK to at least "SDK Platform Android 2.1-update1, API 7, revision 2"

2) In the application.manifest file insert the line

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"></uses-sdk>
```